# How to turn an undefined var to an object, inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

There is something I can't find an answer or an explanation for. Let's take for example the following code:

```
function fn(x){
  x = {value: 10};
}
var a;
fn(a);

alert(a.value); //a is undefined
```

Shouldn't `a = {value: 10};` as we passed it through that function?

Comment: *There is something I can't find an answer or an explanation for.* - Here you go: [JavaScript: Passing by Value or by Reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `x` is locally scoped. You are passing only **values** and not references. So you might need to **return and assign** like this:

```
function fn(x){
  x = {value: 10};
  return x;
}
var a;
a = fn(a);
```

From an [awesome article](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass):

> *When passing in a primitive type variable like a string or a number, the value is passed in **by value**. This means that any changes to that variable while in the function are completely separate from anything that happens outside the function.*

```
function myfunction(x)
{
    // x is equal to 4
    x = 5;
    // x is now equal to 5
}

var x = 4;
alert(x); // x is equal to 4
myfunction(x); 
alert(x); // x is still equal to 4
```

> *Passing in an object, however, passes it in **by reference**. In this case, any property of that object is accessible within the function.*

```
function myobject()
{
    this.value = 5;
}
var o = new myobject();
alert(o.value); // o.value = 5
function objectchanger(fnc)
{
    fnc.value = 6;
}
objectchanger(o);
alert(o.value); // o.value is now equal to 6
```